# Javascript RegExp find and replace empty square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string that contains something like `name="text_field_1[]"` and I need to find and replace the `'1[]'` part so that I can increment like this `'2[]'`, `'3[]'`, etc.

**Code:**

```
$search = new RegExp('1[]', 'g');
$replace = $number + '[]';
$html = $html.replace($search, $replace)
```

Comment: You can use explode in javascript and get a value in array and you can replace a particular array

Comment: Do you want the new replaced numbers to increase sequentially? (Also, when asking a question, it is always good to provide a representative example of before and after text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\d` in your regexp whitch means that onlu numbers used before `[]`.
Also you need to escape `[]` because of it's special characters in regexp.

```
$search = new RegExp('\\d+\\[\\]', 'g');
$replace = $number + '[]';
$html = $html.replace($search, $replace)
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/VJYkc/1/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The problem is that the replace doesn't seem to be working. The number is fine, I just didn't know whether adding brackets into a string like that would get found properly as its not working

Comment: Braces must be escaped within regexps... see my solution above

Answer (score 1):

You can use callbacks.

```
var $counter = 0;

$html = $html.replace(/1\[\]/g, function(){
    ++$counter;
    return $counter+'[]';
});
```

If you need `[]` preceded by any number, you can use `\d`:

```
var $counter = 0;
$html = $html.replace(/\d\[\]/g, function(){
    ++$counter;
    return $counter+'[]';
});
```

**Note:**

- escape brackets, because they are special in regex.
- be sure that in `$html` there is only the pattern you need to replace, or it will replace all `1[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Braces must be escaped within regexps...

```
var yourString="text-field_1[]";
var match=yourString.match(/(\d+)\[\]/);
yourString=yourString.replace(match[0], parseInt(match[1]++)+"[]");
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, would this find and replace in a string globally?

Comment: if you accept his answer, why are you asking? ^^
but yes it will!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something fun. You can pass a function into `string.replace`.

```
  var re = /(\d+)(\[\])/g/;
  html = html.replace(re, function(fullMatch, value, braces) {
    return (parseInt(value, 10)+1) + braces;
  }
```

Now you can replace multiple instances of #[] in your string.